# Passing variable to template view in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need to pass a variable to main template view in Spring. How can I do this. Thanks.

Comment: I have template view, not view that is calling from controller. I have the service that returns user object. I need to pass this user object value to the template view

Comment: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/05/spring-mvc-and-thymeleaf-how-to-acess-data-from-templates.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correct, as you did not provide too much information. But you can't pass a variable to a view without controller. Bind a controller to the URL you want to pass the variable to and put the variable you want to pass in the modelmap. Then you can use it in your view.